# Age Constraint Finding

Tags: prolog

So I have a simpler variation of the Einstein/Zebra puzzle in Prolog.

[image]

And I came up with this possible solution:

```
b_setval(T_age, Var).
friends(L) :- 
    L = [person(A1, B1, T_age), person(A2, B2, C2), person(A3, B3, T_age+3)],
    :
    :
    member(person(_,yang,T_age+3),L),
    member(person(_,_,18),L).
```

But my query `friends(L). - false.` only returns `false` as stated.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `L` is a list of terms that look like `person(...)` (`person/3`). Some of your `member` checks are looking for terms in `L` that look like, `h(...)`, which don't exist in `L`, so those will fail. Also, some of your `member` checks have 3 arguments, (*e.g.*, `member(h,(_,_,15),L)`) and those will generate an error.

Comment: @lurker Sorry, big copy-paste typo. Corrected, but still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the answer of @luker, you can check your answer

```
friends(L) :-
    % 1
    L = [person(ada, _, Ta), person(ama, _, _), person(ana, _, _)],
    % 2
    member(person(_,_,15), L),
    member(person(_,_,17), L),
    member(person(_,_,18), L),
    % 3
    member(person(_, chang, _), L),
    % 4
    member(person(_, yang, Ty), L), Ty is Ta + 3,
    % 5
    member(person(_, thatcher, 17), L).
```

Interesting, this produces 2 results, which is weird for this kind of problem.

Comment: There were some mistakes in my variable naming, but finally I got it!

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem that stands out is the `T_age+3` term in the list `L`. In Prolog, this will not be arithmetically evaluated in-line. It will simply be the term, `'+'(T_age,3)`. So the only element that would match this member of the list would be a term that looks like, `person(X, Y, <something>+3)`. It's unclear whether this is your intention.

You can do a `trace` to see how variables are being instantiated with each `member` call, but let's try doing this manually for illustrative purposes:

```
L = [person(A1, B1, T_age), person(A2, B2, C2), person(A3, B3, T_age+3)],
member(person(ada, _,T_age),L),
...
```

This `member` call should succeed because Prolog can match it to `person(A1, B1, T_age)` in the list by unifying `A1 = ada`. The list `L` now looks like:

```
[person(ada, B1, T_age), person(A2, B2, C2), person(A3, B3, T_age+3)]
```

Moving on to the next `member` call:

```
 member(person(ama, _, _),L),
 ...
```

This can't match the first member, but can match the second by unifying `A2 = ama`. `L` is now:

```
[person(ada, B1, T_age), person(ama, B2, C2), person(A3, B3, T_age+3)]
```

Then you have:

```
 member(person(ana, _, _),L),
```

This can't match the first or second members, but can match the third by unifying `A3 = ana`. `L` is now:

```
[person(ada, B1, T_age), person(ama, B2, C2), person(ana, B3, T_age+3)]
```

The next `member` call is:

```
member(person(_,chang, _),L),
```

Which can match the first member again by unifying `B1 = chang`, so `L` becomes:

```
[person(ada, chang, T_age), person(ama, B2, C2), person(ana, B3, T_age+3)]
```

Then

```
member(person(_,yang,T_age+3),L),
```

This will match the second element of the list by unifying, `B2 = yang` and `C2 = T_age+3`. `L` then becomes:

```
[person(ada, chang, T_age), person(ama, yang, T_age+3), person(ana, B3, T_age+3)]
```

Then

```
member(person(_,thatcher,17),L),
```

This is where you have some trouble. It cannot match the first two elements of `L` because of the second argument. The third argument, `17` cannot match the term, `T_age+3` in the third element of `L`. Remember: Prolog does not solve this as an equation `T_age+3 = 17`. It is just going to see 17 as an atomic integer, and see `T_age+3` as a term with two arguments and find that they don't match. So this `member` call fails, and the whole predicate fails.

Comment: My intention is to match age which is 3 more than some other persons age! My concepts are quite clear now! Can you suggest a possible way to achieve a solution, so that I can get an output of possible persons? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted another version based on your suggestions, that too doesn't work :(

Comment: @jeet do you mean it just fails? Follow the suggestion in my answer and either do a `trace` or walk through it like I did. I think I answered your original question, so if you found my answer to that question acceptable, perhaps you could accept it. :) In your update, the expression, `member(person(_,yang,Y), Y is X+3,L).` is an error because you are passing 3 arguments to `member/2`. Also,. `Y is X+3` will be interpreted as a term (`is(+(X,3),L)`) in this context. As I mentioned in my answer, Prolog doesn't evaluate expressions in-line unless you use a specific arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: @sadly it fails. I am unable to write a predicate that can check if the age of a certain person is 3 more than the other. I did write something like `member(person(_,yang,Y is X+3),L).` but still it didn't work :(

Comment: @jeet in my prior comment, and in my answer, I explained why that won't work. Prolog *will not evaluate expressions* (such as `Y is X + 3`) *in-line*. You need to split it up, for example, `member(person(_, yang, Y), L), Y =:= X + 3` or something similar to that (@malbarbo uses `Ty is Ta + 3`). The arithmetic comparator, `=:=/2` will evaluate expressions. It's described in the Prolog documentation.